# Google Earth Engine script: runs forever without errors but never downloads the .tif file

Tags: geotiff-tiff, google-earth-engine, google-earth, google, download

I am trying to download a base map of California from Google Earth Engine using this code:

```
// Define boundary box
var region = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-124.5,31.3,-110.5,39.8); // minX, minY, maxX, maxY

// using landstat data LE7_L1T
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LE7_L1T') // dIFFERENT satellites 'LC8_L1T', 'MODIS', AST_L1T
  // collect data from these dates
  // the more data, the less cloud coverage
 .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2017-01-01')
 .filterBounds(region);

var composite = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite(collection, 75, 3);

// export it to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
 image: composite,
 description: 'cali-landsat-7-2016-2017',
 scale: 300, // 5000 * 4000 px aproximately, it is pretty big
 maxPixels: 270000000, 
 crs: 'EPSG:32723', // projection
 region: region
});
```

I am trying to save the .tif file in Google Drive. Although the code has worked for me before with other areas, I do not know why is not working now.

I do not receive any error, the script runs for hours but I never get the file. Any solutions? Do you know if there are any limitations?

Comment: Do you have a taskID from one of the tasks that didn't work?

Comment: I am actually having the same problem.
I am trying to export a large image, so I thought it could be related to that.
Here is my script: var DEM = ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4") var boundaries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB/2013") var point = ee.Geometry.Point([77, 28]); var India = boundaries.filterBounds(point) Export.image.toDrive({ image: DEM, description: 'India_DEM', scale: 25000, region: India }); The task keeps 'running' (the small icon keeps turning), but it always says '0s' and if I refresh, the task moves down (does not disappear) and it says 'No recent tasks' on top.
Here is the i

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about the site's focused Q&A format. Answers should only be used to answer the OP's question. If you have a related issue, please use the "Ask Question" button instead (though it's possible this is an issue for GEE tech support).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158022)